# close an activity forever on bottun click

Tags: android, eclipse, forever, activity-finish

My android  app has an users' guide activity which should only start in the first run. It has a button. I wanna use the button to close the activity forever. I used this code:

```
    Button b1001 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1001);
    b1001.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));finish();


        }
    });
```

It doesen't work.
I heard I should use sharedpre/something/ but I Can't.
I need a sample code. thnx

Comment: What you have should be working.  I hope that's helpful.  :(

Comment: Try `Splash.this.finish()` instead to finish the activity. Then save a boolean in shared preference, which you can later check on starting the app. If that has been set, then your app has been started before. You can easily Google How to use SharedPreference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

It's quite clear and doesn't require extensive Android knowledge to implement.
Basically you will be storing a value the first time you run the "tutorial", and the next time the user runs the app, the "tutorial" will not display.

So, this will be used to save the preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);  
editor.commit();
```

And this will be used to retrieve the previously stored:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: "We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country."  google sucks.   where should I paste the codes?

Comment: You should not simply paste the code, it's necessary to understand and adapt it to your specific case (but actually its almost the same). I would use the 2nd snippet first to validate if the variable exists and, if not, create it - using the 1st snippet. After that just set he variable to some value and check it every time the app starts,

Comment: thnx * that was helpful. I'm working on it. I think I found my answer. * thnx